# Can we determine what the wavefunction (states) of a particle is before we decide which measurement to make?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, bells-inequality

If we are measuring spin-up or spin-down then we write the wavefunction (I think) as

$$ \require{physics} \psi = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\uparrow}\rangle+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\downarrow}\rangle  $$

But if we emit a particle, only to make a measurement after a long period of time and distance, and we haven't decided what to measure yet, does the particle still have a wave function? We might measure up/down, left/right or some other quantum parameter.

Would it include *all* possible measurements each with 0 amplitude (since they are infinite as many). And after we decide to measure up or down you have a wavefunction coalescing into two distinct states? Kind of like a sub-collapsing before the actual collapsing that happens during the measurement.

1. What can we know apriori before the measurement, and how is that encoded into the wavefunction?
2. What about two entangled particles? Is there a relationship in their wavefunctions before measurements? Is a relationship like $\int \langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = 0 $ where the two wavefunctions are "orthogonal" to each other, or something like that?

Comment: A single system does not even have a wave function. Only the ensemble (the infinite repetition of the system) has a wave function. That is an easy ontological trap to fall into. Most textbooks don't seem to address it properly. The measurement is not "encoded" in the wave function. The measurement is a completely independent choice because it depends on the structure of an external system that is not identical to the quantum system under measurement.

Comment: @FlatterMann Perhaps you should make explicit the fact that you are a staunch advocate of the [ensemble interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_interpretation) of quantum mechanics, and that your statement is not representative of the other interpretations.

Comment: @J.Murray I am a staunch advocate of reality. If I give you the outcome of one system like "up" and ask you to reconstruct the wave function for me, then you will be completely out of arguments for anything other than wave functions being a representation of properties of the ensemble only. It's really not that difficult. There are trees and there are forests. Forests are not the same as trees. QM is a theory of the forest. It just so happens that there simply is no theory for the single tree in this case. If that irks somebody, then that's too bad.

Comment: @FlatterMann That is a perfectly valid interpretation, but not the only one. In most interpretations, QM **is** the theory of the individual trees, but they simply behave in ways which are often non-intuitive. That may be philosophically unpalatable to you, but it is not an invalid interpretation (and though I would not appeal to proof by popular opinion, it is at least worth noting that the ensemble interpretation is rare among working physicists).

Comment: @J.Murray Those interpretations don't survive first contact with a photomultiplier tube in an atomic physics lab, I am afraid. I never talk about philosophy. I am always talking about actual physical experience. Like I said: the data is "up", please reconstruct the wave function for me. Should be easy, right? I am sure there is an interpretation that can do that. Or is there?

Comment: @FlatterMann It's interesting that [so many physicists and philosophers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1069) who study quantum foundations have alternative views, and that only 3% (N=1) of those polled agree with you, given your assertion that arriving at the correct interpretation is "not that difficult." With respect to your question, why do you think we should be able to reconstruct the pre-measurement state of the system based on the outcome of a single measurement?

Comment: @J.Murray Billions of people agree that there is a bearded guy in the sky who meddles with everything we do and who will get very angry if we don't pay money to his priests, preachers, rabbis and imams. They just can't agree on his name. I have stopped taking the argument that the majority has intellectual weight seriously a long time ago. I don't suggest that the single system has a state, at all. "State" is something we can rightly assign to the ensemble. The individual system either gives us a quantum of energy or it doesn't. Once it does, it can never give us that same quantum again.

Comment: @FlatterMann Then we agree that you hold a valid but **minority** view of quantum mechanics. You are welcome to the opinion that you are among the $\sim 1\%$ of physicists who are correctly interpreting quantum theory and that the rest of us are deluded, but you should make that clear when making highly non-mainstream statements like *a single system does not have a wavefunction* - if for no other reason than it will inform others' decisions on whether to engage with you on these issues.

Comment: @FlatterMann For example, I would have absolutely zero issue with your comment if it began "**In the ensemble interpretation of quantum mechanics**,  [...]"

Comment: @J.Murray I don't hold a view at all. These are simply the facts that we are confronted with in the lab. I can not determine a state from a single measurement, but I can determine at least part of a state by making many measurements. I don't think this is controversial. You can find these facts in a plethora of textbooks and papers that deal with phenomenology in atomic, nuclear etc. physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann In my lab we work with individual particles all the time, e.g. in SHTs/SETs and spin qubits. I have never met anybody in this field who shares your opinions on whether individual particles are described by wave functions or quantum states. This is not an argument against your views, but it suggests that they are not as self-evident as you claim. In any case, clearly this discussion is unproductive so this will be my last comment. Cheers.

Comment: I am thoroughly enjoying this back-and-forth.

Comment: @J.Murray  I didn't find this unproductive at all. I have one more data point of a physicist believing that the wave function applies to a single system without being able to actually back it up with any kind of physical evidence. To me that represents a great failure in the way we teach QM these days. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the particle starts in the state

$$ \require{physics} \psi = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\uparrow}\rangle+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\downarrow}\rangle  $$

and some time elapses, how the state develops depends on the hamiltonian of that particle and any other particle it may interact with. But there is no reason that the state should be very complicated after a long time, especially if there is no strong interaction with another particle.

Answering your specific questions:

> But if we emit a particle, only to make a measurement after a long period of time and distance, and we haven't decided what to measure yet, does the particle still have a wave function?

No matter what, there would be a wavefunction that describes the particle. If the particle interacts with other particles and becomes entangled, the wavefunction which describes that particle would be a shared wavefunction between all entangled particles, but nonetheless you could pull the probabilities for individual particles from it too.

Maybe you consider a joint wave function not to be "a wave function for that particle". In that case you could say it doesn't have a wave function. That is up to you as it is just a matter of semantics.

> Would it include all possible measurements each with 0 amplitude (since they are infinite as many).

No, given any spin state - including the one in your example - there are always infinitely many possible measurements that you can do on it, by measuring the component of its spin along any axis. However given a specific axis, only two outcomes are possible no matter what. And each outcome may have a nonzero probability.

> What can we know apriori before the measurement, and how is that encoded into the wavefunction?

If we know the Hamiltonian of the system, and we know the state in which it started, we can know the probabilities of getting any particular spin result along any axis.

> What about two entangled particles? Is there a relationship in their wavefunctions before measurements? Is a relationship like $\int \langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle = 0 $ where the two wavefunctions are "orthogonal" to each other, or something like that?

They don't have separate wavefunctions. Any two entangled particles have just one wavefunction that describes both of them. And as such there is no sort of orthogonality relation. Take for example the entangled singlet state used in the bell theorem:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow \downarrow \rangle - |\downarrow \uparrow \rangle)$$

This basically reads "Either the first particle has spin up along the z-axis and the second spin down, or vice versa". The minus sign encodes information about probabilities for measuring along other axes.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your spin 1/2 wave function:

$$ \require{physics} \psi = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\uparrow}\rangle+\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |{\downarrow}\rangle = |\rightarrow\rangle $$

where:

$$|\rightarrow\rangle \equiv |S=\tfrac 1 2, S_x=\tfrac 1 2 \rangle $$

That is, it is an eigenstate of the $\hat S_x$ operator.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're conceptualizing a wavefunction as a big statistical ensemble of all possible outcomes of measurements. That's not what it is. In your example, let $u$ be the spin-up wavefunction and $v$ the spin-down wavefunction. Let's not worry about the normalization factors of $1/\sqrt{2}$ for now. Then your $u+v$ is not the same wavefunction as $u-v$, nor is it the same state. The phases matter.

If the phases *didn't* matter, then you'd be talking about a statistical ensemble of many electrons, which is described by a density matrix, not a single wavefunction (not even a pure-state wavefunction of many electrons).

Consider the double-slit experiment, and now redefine $u$ as a wavefunction in which the wave is only emerging through the left slit, and $v$ as a wavefunction in which the wave is emerging through the right slit. Let's say $u$ and $v$ are in phase at the slits. Then $u+v$ gives an interference pattern in which there is a maximum at the center, while $u-v$ gives a minimum at the center.

Measurement doesn't have any fundamental logical significance in quantum mechanics. Wavefunctions are what they are, regardless of whether there is any measurement. Measurement is just a certain type of physical interaction in which decoherence takes place.

Comment: The quantum mechanical ensemble is not a statistical ensemble, but it is an ensemble. Let's say I tell you that the spin after a measurement was "up". What was the wave function? See the problem?